# import module form package using string configuration

Tags: python, django, module, python-import

In my python application I import some configuration related the module that I want to import, so how to do that using string conf like shown in below example?

For exmpple I use pakage

```
package="pak.pak1"
module="moduleA"
```

And I want to do folwing

```
from package import module
```

but i have the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named moudleA

Comment: does your package have `__init__.py`?

Comment: Maybe this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path

Comment: yes i have it ,, my probelm is how to use this importation as a confugration saved in string variable

Comment: I believe you may have a typo somewhere. You have `module="moduleA"`, but your error is saying `moudleA`. They aren't spelled the same.

Comment: this is just an exmple not a real code, any where i find a solution to my question  its laike this

Comment: my code def m():
    import importlib
    function_string ='m.aa.bb.show'
    pak,mod_name,clas_name, func_name = function_string.rsplit('.')
    mod = importlib.import_module(pak+'.'+mod_name)
    print(mod_name)
    print(clas_name)
    print(func_name)
    clas=getattr(mod, clas_name)
    func = getattr(clas, func_name)
    func(33)   
    

m()   //////////////////

Comment: class aa:
    def serv(self):
        print("hello wrold")
class bb:
    def show(ff):
        print('gggggggggggggg',ff)
        
def h(g):
    print("ppppppppppppppppp  ",g)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class aa:
    def serv(self):
        print("hello wrold")
class bb:
    def show(ff):
        print('gggggggggggggg',ff)

def h(g):
    print("ppppppppppppppppp  ",g)
#/////////////////////////////////////////
def m():
    import importlib
    function_string ='m.aa.bb.show'
    pak,mod_name,clas_name, func_name = function_string.rsplit('.')
    mod = importlib.import_module(pak+'.'+mod_name)
    print(mod_name)
    print(clas_name)
    print(func_name)
    clas=getattr(mod, clas_name)
    func = getattr(clas, func_name)
    func(33)   
m()
```